# Django Override blocks in template from within iframe

Tags: django, templates, iframe, block

I have a template structured as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title> {%block title %} Default title {% endblock %} </title> </head>
<body>
<iframe>
<head> <title> {% block title %} Title for frame {% endblock %} </title> </head>
<body> Main content. This is what people see on the web page. </body>
</iframe>
<!-- Content that I do not want to reload every time. A player, to be precise. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Within the iframe, I inherit templates and so on, to display my final page. The title block within the iframe gets replaced properly, and the title of the iframe is what it should be.

However, I want to replace the title of the parent frame, when I load a page inside the iframe. Is it possible to do this? I don't want to do it via Javascript, because that defeats the purpose of SEO. I want the title to be changed when the page is loaded itself, from the server side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using an `iframe`? The way you describe it, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I need that structure to not reload certain parts of the page. I'm sorry I didn't mention that. I have a player that I don't want to reinitialize every time a new page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have two blocks named with name `title`. Rename one of them and everything should work fine. The Django template construction isn't influenced at all if you are working with `iframe` or with any other element.

EDIT:
When an `iframe` gets a new location it sends a request to the server and renders *all* of its response *inside* the `iframe`. So no it is not possible to leverage Django's template system for a change in the `iframe`'s parent site.

I am no SEO expert but using an `iframe` like this will probably not be liked by a search engine anyway. You should implement the traditional click-pageload way. If you want to speed things up you can use JavaScript on top of that. Captchure your menu clicks and load the needed parts of the site asynchronously. This way both you and your search engine can be happy :)

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't seem to work. I replaced the title block outside the iframe with {% block maintitle %} and defined both {% block title %} and {% block maintitle %} in my templates. But it only replaces the {% title %} of the parent template inside the iframe and not the main one.

Comment: I can't see any reason why that shouldn't work. Are you sure you have no typo or something like that?

Comment: Pretty sure, Maccesch. I double checked, because it just seemed really easy!

Comment: Ping! No answers? I'm still facing this issue!

Comment: What you describe is a default use case for django templates. It works! Something else is going on here.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the question, or if it really is that simple. There is a block in the webpage, called, say, {% block maintitle %}. Now, there is an iframe in the webpage, which, for all practical purposes, is independent of the main page. Will the blocks in the template being loaded inside the iframe really replace the blocks in the template _outside_ the iframe? It doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Problem is, I _have_ to use an iframe because there are certain parts of the website that I do not want to refresh. Worrying about SEO is one thing, but I'm right now primarily focused on how to change the title without using javascript. Thanks for the reply anyway.